# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'srcCompat' with value '@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher') in eclispe

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I have follow the tutorial to call image, but I got this message error to load the source with my eclipse. I don't what is the problem. How can I solved it?
here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:
            android:id="@+id/userImg" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'srcCompat'
>   with value '@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher')

You should use

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
```

instead of

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image"
```

**Site Note** : If you have been using `Eclipse` with `ADT`, be aware that `Android Studio` is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to `Android Studio` to receive all the latest IDE updates.

Current projects built in `Eclipse` should still work well enough, but taking advantage of new Android features will be harder and harder from here on out. Projects can be imported into `Android Studio` with the `File>New>Import Project` menu.

Comment: It works well thank you. I will change to use android studio.